# Distributing shell scripts in OSX

Tags: macos, shell

I need to distribute a shell script I made in OSX.  I gave it the .command extension so it could just be double-clicked on to open, but when I send it to people it loses the executable permission.

Is there any way I can distribute this without users having to go in a set the executable permission themselves?  I'd rather not have to make a document to show everyone how to do that.

Comment: Put it in a tarball? Put it in a dmg?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Marked for move to Superuser. Agreed on what Etan said. Otherwise give explicit instructions with your distribution to set the rights via Terminal.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be an appropriate site for this question

Comment: In fact, [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) looks like something you'd want to look into.